# How to move c# form app without default border

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi there I wrote a code for moving the windows form application without default border style and I can move it . But when i move it fast the panel don't follows the mouse . How can I fix that ?

```
bool mouseDown = false;
int mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDown && Control.MouseButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left)) {

        this.SetDesktopLocation(MousePosition.X - mouseX, MousePosition.Y - mouseY);
    }
}

private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = true;
    mouseX = e.X;
    mouseY = e.Y; 
}

private void MouseUpp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = false; 
}
```

Comment: First of all, what is your project type(WinForms, WPF)? Second, there is nothing to _"fix"_.

Comment: Can u post a screenshot which gives the clear idea about your problem?

Comment: It's WinForms.  When the mouse cursor moves fast (outside of menu strip ) the form don't follows mouse cursor

Comment: I set the form border style property to none and i create a menu strip for make a flat app  and i want to move this form when users clicked at menu strip (or something like that ) and move mouse that form follows the mouse. but when I move fast : the cursor get outside from menu strip and form don't follow the mouse

Comment: _"but when I move fast : the cursor get outside from menu strip and form don't follow the mouse"_ - Can I know the reason behind that?

Comment: My English is very awful :) so I can't explain it well
... All that method I define in above is for menu strip mouse events and just work when i click or move into the menu strip collision and when I move quickly and the mouse moves out of collision , it does not work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the nice little user32 function right here:

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

That will handle the moving much faster.

Thanks to @[Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey)

Comment: Thank you . It works but i don't know how it works . If you have a tutorial for this code please send me :)

Comment: @amirmehr First you release the capture with `ReleaseCapture()` which means the mouse input is now global, not captured and bound to the window because its the active window. Then you use `SendMessage` which is a universal function. In this case `SendMessage` sends "cursor is now holding down on border" to Windows. Even if there is no border you can actually grab, `SendMessage` simulates it. Windows knows which window it should move because you give the window `Handle` with the `SendMessage-Function` Greetings and please mark my answer as "answer" ;)